# ListView NullpointerException issue at BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception

I have tried to make a `ListView` using a `CustomViewAdapter`, but I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

**MainActivity:**

```
private Context context=this;
private ListView listView;
private List<AlarmModel> alarms;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAlarm);

    // get data from SQLite
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);

    db.addAlarmDB(new AlarmModel());
    db.addAlarmDB(new AlarmModel());
    alarms = db.getAllAlarmDB();


    //adding adapter
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(context,alarms);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**This is my CustomListViewAdapter along with ViewHolder:**

```
public class CustomListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<AlarmModel> alarmListData = new ArrayList<>();

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, List<AlarmModel> data){
    this.context = context;
    this.alarmListData = data;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
}

//this is ViewHolder class
public class ViewHolder{
    TextView alarmTimeText;
    TextView alarmTitleText;
    Switch alarmStatusSwitch;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return alarmListData.size();
}

@Override
public AlarmModel getItem(int position) {
    return alarmListData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder hold;

    //bind with list view
    if (convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_list_content,null);
        hold = new ViewHolder();
        hold.alarmTitleText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarmTImeText);
        hold.alarmTitleText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarmTitleText);
        hold.alarmStatusSwitch = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alarmStatusSwitch);
        convertView.setTag(hold);
    }else{
        hold = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    /// get data from model
    AlarmModel alarmData = getItem(position);
    hold.alarmTimeText.setText(alarmData.getTime());
    hold.alarmTitleText.setText(alarmData.getTitle());

    //this is for switch of alarm status
    if(alarmData.getStatus()==1){
        hold.alarmStatusSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }else{
        hold.alarmStatusSwitch.setChecked(false);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

**Logcat:**

[gist](https://gist.github.com/sz-ashik440/5d1112cbcddbb7cb67a8)

**PS:** At `CustomListViewAdapter.java:72` `alarmData` object isn't empty. I have checked it with Log.d.

Comment: you never assign `hold. alarmTimeText `, but twice  `hold. alarmTitleText`

Comment: Which is your line no 72 in custom adapter ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks :) This was a stupid mistake by me.